# ZipArchive with password in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I need to decompress a Zip file protected by a password in my Windows Store App. For archives without password I use `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`, but it does not support password protected archives. Is there another way? None of the other libs like SharpZipLib or DotNetZip work with WinRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it using just the WinRT APIs. The only option is to use a [paid library by Component One](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ZipWinRT/), but it only support the standard Zip encypriton (CryptoZip) not AES used by WinZip.

Comment: is there still no other Option?

Comment: SharpCompress now has a WinRT version, finally.

Comment: thanks for the info. in the end, we used Chilkat in our project. You have to pay for it too, but it works quite well.